# jQuery on change event for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-item">
 <label>Disability: </label>
  <div class="form-radios student_course_disablity">
    <div class="form-item" id="edit-student-course-disability-not-stated-wrapper">
     <label class="option" for="edit-student-course-disability-not-stated">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-student-course-disability-not-stated" name="student[course][disability]" value="not_stated" checked="checked" class="form-radio student_course_disablity">  Not Stated</label>
    </div>
 <div class="form-item" id="edit-student-course-disability-yes-wrapper">
   <label class="option" for="edit-student-course-disability-yes">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-student-course-disability-yes" name="student[course][disability]" value="yes" class="form-radio student_course_disablity"> Yes</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-item" id="edit-student-course-disability-no-wrapper">
   <label class="option" for="edit-student-course-disability-no">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-student-course-disability-no" name="student[course][disability]" value="no" class="form-radio student_course_disablity"> No</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to run onchange event for this radio button:

I've tried this method:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=student[course][disability]]').change(function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

But no luck

Comment: You should use `class` or `id` for `change` `event`

Comment: `[name="student[course][disability]"]` would work (ie. quote the attribute value), otherwise you'd need to escape the square brackets, `[name=student\\[course\\]\\[disability\\]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put name in double quote like below. Hope this will help.

```
$('input[type=radio][name="student[course][disability]"]').change(function () {   
    alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better you group by the `class` rather than using `name` selector, that too without `"` quotes. You might want to use: `'input[name="student[course][disability]"]'`.

```
$('input.student-course-disability').on("change click", function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

Add `click` event too, just in case. Don't forget to give the `class` to the `<input />` elements.

I have already given you the best solution, but for your updated solution:

```
$('input[name="student[course][disability]"]').change(function () {   
    alert('hi');
});
```